# How to send message to emulator in android using a script?

Tags: android, emulation, message

I know I can send message to my emulator via DDMS, but is there any php script or some other script from which I can send message to emulator?

Comment: You can use shell script and execute it in ubuntu terminal      telnet localhost 5554
sms send senderPhoneNumber textmessage

Comment: Weel, it does work... The message comes to my emulator but I have used a listener which listens that message and displays the same using toast. As the message comes this listener is invoked and my app crashes.!!! I couldn't figure out why..